# Method db.collection.remove is not implemented

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm using mongo:3.6 and trying to remove a document from DB and getting this error.

query:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').remove({_id: ObjectId('5ebe919cf6c0d7a304ef3a9e')}, {justOne: true});
```

and error:

```
Method db.collection.remove is not implemented
```

What wrong with this?

Comment: `remove` is deprecated (at least in the latest nodejs driver). Have you tried `deleteOne` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, 'remove' command probably deprecated and 'deleteOne' works great.